# Retaining type info in typescript function return value

Tags: typescript

Curious how I would get the following to work in typescript.  `tempA` copies x.a to x.temp and returns it, and `tempB` does the same to x.b.  Now, for whatever reason calling `tempA` makes the compiler seem to forget that there's a `b` field on `x`.  Is there a way to get past this?  Or is there a github issue tracking this pattern / what feature name would it be filed under?

```
let tempA = (x: { a: number; temp?: number}) => {
    x.temp = x.a;
    return x;
}

let tempB = (x: { b: number; temp?: number}) => {
    x.temp = x.b
    return x;
}

let x = { a: 4, b: 3 };
let y = tempA(x);
let z = tempB(y); // Can't! y.b does not exist (even though it does)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the parameter type of `x` is declared as `{ a: number; temp?: number }`, and the function returns `x`, the return type is inferred as `{ a: number, temp?: number }`. Therefore, that's the type of `y`, so Typescript doesn't know that `y` has a property named `b`.

You can solve this by making the function generic, so it guarantees to return something of the same type as its argument:

```js
function tempA<T extends { a: number; temp?: number }>(x: T): T {
    x.temp = x.a;
    return x;
}
```

That's good enough for your sample code, but not as strict as possible; the return type suggests that the object might not have a `temp` property, when in reality we can guarantee that it does have this property. We can write a stricter return type using an intersection `&`; this is a bit messier, so you may or may not prefer it depending on your requirements.

```js
function tempA<T extends { a: number; temp?: number }>(x: T): T & { temp: number }
{
    x.temp = x.a;
    return x as T & { temp: number };
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgWwA4EEA8AVRFAD1TABMBnRAb0QEMAuRMENAIxQCcBuZdDAPxMW7LogC+APgAURJngCU8mgChE6xEQB0qTIgC8mrXW5qNnFFBCckRU+JUrQkWAj6YAQvkIkU5KrRswqwcPO6CwaKcEjJyiIrK1Gbq2roYBkZsyYgWVjaa9o4ANpaaGbSMiAAsADSIQYgAzBKmJVCIAJ4ZaViyCq2lAF7d-B7SHf2IAPRTiADucJwA1hQqQA)

Answer (score 0):

Here, x has the following (inferred) type signature:

```js
let x: {a: number, b: number} = {a: 4, b: 3}
```

After this, you pass it into a method `tempA` which has the following inferred type signature:

```
(x: { a: number; temp?: number }) => { a: number; temp?: number }
```

Now you see the problem. When you write,

```
let y: { a: number; temp?: number } = tempA(x);
```

obviously "b" is missing. This is **not** a bug or missing feature. Consider the following case:

```
let y = tempA({ a: 4 });
// Suppress compiler warnings
// @ts-ignore
let z: { b: number; temp?: number} = tempB(y) 
// z.b = undefined, violates type constraints
```

To solve your issue, you'll need to fundamentally change your type signatures.

```
// Guarantee that any 'x' passed to tempA will have a 'b' property
let tempA = (x: { a: number; b: number; temp?: number}) => {
    x.temp = x.a;
    return x;
}

let tempB = (x: { b: number; temp?: number}) => {
    x.temp = x.b
    return x;
}

let x = { a: 4, b: 3 };
let y = tempA(x);
let z = tempB(y); // Works :D
```